# NextJS change data in API from component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, next.js

I've got a problem with updating data from API in NextJS. I want to increment the value by clicking on the button and then update the API.
My local JSON file is in at http:localhost/api/data

**data.js:**

```js
export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ value: 0 })
}
```

I want to update this value from Home component

**index.js:**

```js
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Home({data) {
  const [currentData, setCurrentData] = useState(data)
  return (
    <div>
      {data.value}
      <button onClick={(e) => setCurrentData(currentData.value + 1)}>+</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/data')
  const data = await res.json()
  return {
    props: { data },
  }
}
```

Is there any way to do it? If something is unclear feel free to ask :)

Comment: Hi! i dont know if i understood it 100% but, in that code you will be showing always data that cames from the API. If you want to update the API, you should do an async req (put/patch) to the API updating the value

Comment: Are you asking how to update the server-side data?  For that you'd create another server-side endpoint (likely a POST, PUT, or PATCH request as you see fit) to persist the updated data wherever/however you want to persist it (and potentially return the new data).  Then your client-side code would invoke that server-side operation, and when it completes would update the client-side data.  Can you clarify specifically what you're trying that isn't working as expected?

Comment: @David thanks for your answer, this is exactly what I was looking for. I simply couldn't figure out how to update server-side data :)

Comment: @Stairss: First you'd need to store that data somewhere.  Currently the code shown returns a static hard-coded value.  You could store data in a database, in a file, etc.  Your current server-side operation would read and return that data to the client, and a separate operation would update that data.